# @JsonFormat Jackson Annotation Incorrectly Outputs Date due to GMT Difference

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have DTO that I'm outputting to Jackson where a field is defined as

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
Date reportingDate;
```

That field is stored in the Postgres DB as `Timestamp Without Timezone`, and is e.g.

```
2019-04-01 22:04:40.353
```

The JSON for this field is incorrectly output to `2019-04-02`. I verified that the problem occurs due to Jackson adding +5 to my value for the Time Zone difference from GMT. This is incorrect and I should only get the exact Date Value as coming back from the DB. Is my Jackson configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the `timezone` attribute as below.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy", timezone = "America/New_York")
Date reportingDate;
```

Now it doesn't add +5 to make it GMT.